# Mostrar en details una lista de TODOS los materiales que pertenecen a dos tablas que tengan relacion uno a muchos con MVC 5 y EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, model-view-controller

Saludos a todos soy nuevo en **MVC** y tengo un problema para mostrar lo del siguiente modelo, la tabla *SalidaMaterial* almacena los permisos sobre algun tipo de *material* que vaya de salida, la tabla *LineaSalidaMaterial* almacena especificamente los materiales que van a salir con respecto al permiso asociado de la tabla *SalidaMaterial*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice una clase modelo donde ahí agrego las dos tablas

```
public class SalidaMaterial_LineaSalidaMaterial{
    //obtiene las tablas automaticamenete
    public SalidaMaterial salidaMaterial { get; set; }
    public LineaSalidaMaterial lineaSalidaMaterial { get; set; }
}
```

En la parte de **Details.cshtml** mando llamar a ese modelo para mostrarlo en la vista

```
@model _VigilanciaIMO.Models.SalidaMaterial_LineaSalidaMaterial
```

En lo que tengo problema es en lo siguiente, encontré un ejemplo del cual me basé pero este ejemplo solo me obtiene UN SOLO registro y  lo que me interesa es mostrar TODOS los que pertenezcan a la tabla *SalidaMaterial*.

Para eso tengo la siguiente clase **SalMat_LinSalMat_Mostrar.cs** con el siguiente método

```
public class SalMat_LinSalMat_Mostrar {

    private VigilanciaEntities db = new VigilanciaEntities();

    public SalidaMaterial mostrarInformacion(int id){  
        try{
            var lista = 
                (
                    from s in db.SALIDAMATERIAL
                    join l in db.LINEASALIDAMATERIAL
                    on s.IdSalidaMaterial equals l.IdSalidaMaterialF
                    where s.IdSalidaMaterial == id
                    select s
                ).ToList();
            return lista.First();
           /* NECESITO MOSTRAR TODOS LOS REGISTROS PERTENECIENTES*/
        } catch (Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Y en el controlador en la parte de Details hago lo siguiente pero para mostrar solo un registro.

```
    // GET: AutorizarSalidaMaterial/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
       SalidaMaterial_LineaSalidaMaterial modelo = new SalidaMaterial_LineaSalidaMaterial();
        //el valor 19 es un valor fijo para pruebas
        modelo.salidaMaterial = new SalMat_LinSalMat_Mostrar().mostrarInformacion(19);
        modelo.lineaSalidaMaterial = modelo.salidaMaterial.LINEASALIDAMATERIAL.First();
        //hacer que muestre mas de uno 
        //buscar el contrario de FirstOrDefault()
        return View(modelo);
    }
```

Me podrían a ayudar por favor a resolver este detalle.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente tengas que hacer varios toques mas. Pero para empezar debes arreglar las siguientes cosas:

```
public List<SalidaMaterial> mostrarInformacion(int id){  
    try{
        var lista = 
            (
                from s in db.SALIDAMATERIAL
                join l in db.LINEASALIDAMATERIAL
                on s.IdSalidaMaterial equals l.IdSalidaMaterialF
                where s.IdSalidaMaterial == id
                select s
            ).ToList();
        return lista;
    } catch (Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Como esten armados tus objetos, puede que una List no te alcance y necesites otro tipo de objeto. Fijate que saque del return el First, que era el que te hacia devolver el primero. Puede que en lugar de list necesites Array o InmutableArray.

Tu controller deberia quedar algo asi:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
   SalidaMaterial_LineaSalidaMaterial modelo = new SalidaMaterial_LineaSalidaMaterial();
    //el valor 19 es un valor fijo para pruebas
    modelo.salidaMaterial = new SalMat_LinSalMat_Mostrar().mostrarInformacion(19); <-- Hay que cambiar el objeto, para que acepte una lista, array....
    modelo.lineaSalidaMaterial = modelo.salidaMaterial.LINEASALIDAMATERIAL.First(); <-- first siempre devuelve el primero, sacalo y devuelve todo lo que queres. Tal vez tengas que usar, ToList()?
    //hacer que muestre mas de uno 
    //buscar el contrario de FirstOrDefault()
    return View(modelo);
}
```

Tu objeto tambien deberia cambiar:

```
public class SalidaMaterial_LineaSalidaMaterial{
    //obtiene las tablas automaticamenete
    public List<SalidaMaterial> salidaMaterial { get; set; }
    public List<LineaSalidaMaterial> lineaSalidaMaterial { get; set; }
}
```